# Easil js - removing an item from a container - not a stage

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'm building a drawing application - and the doodles are bound to a container (not a stage) as a child.

The problem though - is when I try and undo the doodles - nothing happens. I try and remove the children from the container - but nothing is happening - if I start to try and update cache or update stage - nothing happens. - updating the cache on the container just seems to clear everything.

```
this.stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas'); 

this.stageArea  = new createjs.Container();
this.stage.addChild(this.stageArea);

var drawingCanvas = new createjs.Shape();
drawingCanvas.shadow = new createjs.Shadow('#0066cc',1, 1, 30);

app.stageArea.addChild(drawingCanvas);    

function undoHandler = function(){
    console.log("undo bit");
    if(app.stageArea.children.length > 1){
        var lastChild = app.stageArea.children.pop(1);
        app.stageArea.removeChild(lastChild);
        app.stage.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea works in this concept - http://jsfiddle.net/JTqvJ/166/

Comment: I don't understand why in the code base I am working on - this doesn't work. What would prevent the removal of children drawing Canvas shapes from the container?

Comment: I recommend against manually removing the child from the children list, unless you need to do something that the Container APIs does not support. In this case, `removeChild()` WILL remove it from the child list for you. You can also use `container.numChildren` instead of accessing the children array to get the length.